# iPod Touch on device debugging crashes (EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION, EXC_BAD_ACCESS)

Tags: iphone, xcode, debugging, ipod-touch, exc-bad-access

I'm using iPod Touch 2G as a developement device with Xcode 3.1.3. When I try to trace the execution on the device from a breakpoint in the debugger I get EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION, EXC_BAD_ACCESS or some error with debugger not being able do disassemble something. The same thing will work properly on iPhone Simulator. Previously I've been able to trace the execution from a breakpoint on some other iPod Touch 2G and iPhone 3G devices.

If not interrupted with a breakpoint the app will work properly. Also before any "stepping" I can investigate variables currently on the stack and their values seem to be correct.

Is it possible that the device is somehow flawed or should I look into my project configuration more closely (and what should I look for)?

EDIT: After playing with project configuration I've found that debugger starts to act normally after disabling "Compile for Thumb" option. The question now is why is it so?

Answer (score 1):

Check your build setting, whether it was in iOS 3.2 or lower than latest. This issue I have solved by changing the Base SDK to the latest iOS 4.0 in my project settings.

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

This post saved me hours.  It should be all you need to dig deep enough to see just what the root issue is.  http://www.codza.com/how-to-debug-exc_bad_access-on-iphone

Good Luck!